# JQuery DataTables - fnReloadAjax() How to reload the fnDrawCallback or fnInitComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a dataTable of users that I am allowing admins to edit the information for. But the issue is that in order to bind jquery functions to certain cells in the datatables is to list the functions in either the fnDrawCallback or fnInitComplete options of the datatable initialization. However, when a user updates a row and the fnReloadAjax is executed (to display the new changes), all the JQuery that was binded to the table cells is no longer available!
I have tried placing all the JQuery code in both fnDrawCallback and fnInitComplete and both have the same result.
Any ideas?

```
    var oTable = $('.admin_users').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": 'sql/admin_users.php',       
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bStateSave": true, //Use a cookie to save current display of items
    "aoColumns": [
        {"asSorting": [  ]},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "date", "sClass":"center" }
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function(){
            //Edit row
            $('.button_edit').click(function(){
                $(':input[type="text"]').val('');
                $(':input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
                $('.admin_edit_button.button_update').attr('id',$(this).attr('id'));
                $('.admin_edit_user').slideDown();
                var userid = $(this).attr('id');
                //GET USER INFO
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'sql/admin_edit',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: 'getinfo=true&userid='+userid,
                    success: function(data){
                        //FILL IN INPUTS WITH USER VALUES
                    }
                });
                //UPDATE CHANGES
                $('.admin_edit_button.button_update').click(function(){
                    //GET NEW/UNCHANGED VALUES
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'sql/admin_edit.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        async: false,
                        data: //SEND DATA HERE,
                        success: function(response){
                            if(response=='true'){
                                $(':input[type="text"]').val('');
                                $(':input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
                                $('.admin_edit_user').slideToggle(function(){oTable.fnReloadAjax()});

                                alert("Success!");
                            }
                            if(response=='false')
                                alert('Failed to update user');
                        },
                        error: function(response){
                                alert('Failed to update user');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            $('.button_cancel').click(function(){
                $('.admin_edit_user').slideUp();
                $(':input[type="text"]').val('');
                $(':input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
            });
    },
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
     "fnInitComplete": function() {
            oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try delegation.

```
...
fnInitCallback: function(settings){
    $('tbody',settings.nTableWrapper).delegate('.button_edit', 'click', function(){
        // Edit handler
    });

    // Etc.
}
```

`tbody` shouldn't get blown away with an ajax reload.